# How to search for files with CFtpFileFind::FileFind() method?

Tags: c++, mfc

I created `m_pFileFind` using `CFtpFileFind` class.

I tried to search all files with `FindFile()` by performing dynamic allocation, but 0 is returned and the search is not available.

I tried debugging by referring to Microsoft docs, but I couldn't figure out the cause.

Please give me detailed advice.

```cpp
void CMFC_FTPDlg::ShowList()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectFTP();
        m_pFileFind = new CFtpFileFind(m_pConnection);

        m_pConnection->SetCurrentDirectory(_T("test"));
        m_pConnection->GetCurrentDirectory(m_strDir);
        MessageBox(m_strDir);
        
        BOOL bWorking = m_pFileFind->FindFile(_T("*"));
        while (bWorking)
        {
            // use finder.GetFileURL() as needed...
            m_pFileFind->FindNextFile();

            if (m_pFileFind->IsNormal())
            {
                //파일의 이름
                CString strfileName =  m_pFileFind->GetFileName();

                m_List.AddString(strfileName);   
            }
            else if (m_pFileFind->IsDirectory())
            {
                //파일의 이름
                CString strDireName = m_pFileFind->GetFileName();

                m_List.AddString(strDireName);   
            }
        }
    }
    catch(CInternetException* pEx)
    {
        pEx->ReportError(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        m_pConnection = NULL;
        pEx->Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: *but I couldn't figure out the cause* -- Where is the indication that you debugged the code?  Does the `while` loop not execute?  Does it execute?  If so, what values are returned on each iteration?  Does `new` throw an exception?  Where does the `0` return value come into play?  Maybe there are no files?  etc. etc.  You need to detail specifically what you observed while you are debugging the code.

Comment: Why are you calling `FindFile()` multiple times in a loop? You need to call it only once, and then use `FindNextFile()` to continue the loop. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66450657/65863) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450393/) already showed you how to do that, so why are you asking this question again?

Comment: When checking by passing the return value of FileFind() as a BOOL variable, 0 is returned. There are 3 txt files in the test directory on my FTP server.
FileFind returns 0 and the while statement is not executed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
I've done it the way you told me, but BOOL bWorking = m_pFileFind-> FindFile (_T ("*")); The return value is returning 0. I don't know the cause even if I browse the microdocuments.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpfilefind-class#findfile): "*Return Value: Nonzero if successful; otherwise 0. **To get extended error information, call the Win32 function GetLastError**.*" So, what does `GetLastError()` return for you when `FindFile()` returns 0?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Printing GetLastError returns 12003.

Comment: @SJW error 12003 is `ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR`. Use [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetlastresponseinfow) to get more details.

Comment: You never update the value of bWorking so it will stay in an eternal loop.

Comment: See my answer which also raises another issue with your logic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the documentation for [`CFtpFileFind::FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpfilefind-class?view=msvc-160#findnextfile) where it states:

> ## Return Value
>
> Nonzero if there are more files; zero if the file found
> is the last one in the directory or if an error occurred. To get
> extended error information, call the Win32 function `GetLastError`. If
> the file found is the last file in the directory, or if no matching
> files can be found, the `GetLastError` function returns
> `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`.

In your code you have:

```
BOOL bWorking = m_pFileFind->FindFile(_T("*"));
while (bWorking)
{
    // use finder.GetFileURL() as needed...
    m_pFileFind->FindNextFile();

    // Snipped
}
```

You are never updating the `bWorking` variable inside the loop. Change it to:

```
BOOL bWorking = m_pFileFind->FindFile(_T("*"));
while (bWorking)
{
    // Work here on the file (since you have already found the first file before
    // starting the loop

    // Snipped

    bWorking = m_pFileFind->FindNextFile();
}
```

Comment: I made changes according to your advice. But FileFind's LastErrorCode is 12003. I searched for it and saw some advice, but I can't get any sense of it. Can you show me how to solve this with a simple example code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275851/error-12003-ftp-file-upload-error

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the answer. I solved the problem. It was a problem for the passive mode!!